# Android: Retrofit fails when trying to get data from local network

Tags: java, android

I am using retrofit for all my API calls, problem is that I want to read data from local network (ESP device) hosting http server. It turns out that while connected to desired network, and having mobile data turned on - the call fails . Once mobile data is disabled this works perfectly. How the wifi device registration should be handled properly?